# Please help me with one sentence - struggling

Tags: word-choice

> Which horse shall we ___ in the 2.17 race?

A. back
B. win
C. place
D. bet

I think something is wrong with the question. “Bet” seems to be the first choice but “on” is missing.

Comment: "Back" I think be a good option.

Comment: Back is the correct answer. It means "to bet on".

Comment: Your instinct was right. When you realize that “Bet” seems to be the first choice but “on” is missing, you cannot mark that answer as right. Call it a trap, but the test makers are begging you not to notice that you would need "on" to make that right. As is, it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I would choose back. Sometimes if I'm unsure, I use synonyms to replace the target word to see if the sentence will still make sense.